# Getting the xaml name of a control using a MouseMove event

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, mousemove

I have 2 DataGrid's.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"  />


 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2"  />
```

Is it possible to get the xaml Name of the DataGrid I'm currently on from a MouseMove event?

Thanks!

Edit:
I'm using a third party source - Syncfusion in order to create a SfDataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

ABC.xaml

```
<SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" MouseEnter="DG_OnMouseEnter" />
<SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" MouseEnter="DG_OnMouseEnter" />
```

ABC.xaml.cs [CodeBehind]

```
private void DG_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(((FrameworkElement) sender).Name);
    if (sender is SfDataGrid) e.Handled = true; //prevent event-execution of childs
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

I didn't mention but I'm using a third party source - I'm using Syncfusion to create a SfDataGrid.

Any attempt to work around your suggestion didn't succeed.

Comment: @dov: I updated my answer. can you check if the DG_OnMouseMove is getting called (use a breakpoint)... You could also use Event MouseEnter...

Comment: I've tried updating my code, I get "PART_VisualContainer" as the name (which is correct for some reason).

Comment: @dov: Updated my answer